# Regex for repated capturing of groups between certain identifiers

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, regex-group

Here is a example of the data I'm trying to parse:

```
//lots of html source code
['unimportant','example data']
$(function() {

 var graph = new lineChart('chart-im-looking-for',
 {
  'width' : 1100, 'height' : 600,
  'font' : 'Arial',
  //more javascript code here
  'groups':
    [
    {
    //more javascript code here
    'values' : [
        {'x':1386374400, 'y':49.82, 'hover':['12/7',49.82], 'xlabel':'12/7'},
        {'x':1386460800, 'y':47.67, 'hover':['12/8',47.67], 'xlabel':'12/8'},
        {'x':1386547200, 'y':45.43, 'hover':['12/9',45.43], 'xlabel':'12/9'},
        {'x':1386633600, 'y':47, 'hover':['12/10',47], 'xlabel':'12/10'},
        {'x':1386720000, 'y':46.81, 'hover':['12/11',46.81], 'xlabel':'12/11'}
    ]
    }
    ]
  });
['unimportant','example data']
//lots of html source code
```

I need to get the data from the 'hover' arrays in two groups. Note that there are more charts in the same format before and after the chart whose data I need to get, so I need to identify the right one by its id ('chart-im-looking-for', in this example).

I tried the following regex:

```
(?<=lineChart\('chart-im-looking-for'.*?'values'.*?)\['(.*?)',(.*?)]
```

If I use it with the 'dot matches newline' option, it captures all the data in the values array. However, I don't know how to limit the matching to the values array only, so it captures the 'unimportant example data' after the end of the array. I'm testing with RegexBuddy, and I'll be using .net regex. Any help, please?

**Edit:** I'd rather avoid making any assumptions about the formatting of the document in the regex, such as the position of whitespaces (including line breaks).

Comment: What is currently matched? I assume that all `[...]` arrays are matched that occur after `'values'` (one at a time), because the look-behind matches for all of them.

Comment: @Njol, yes, all arrays after 'values' are being matched. Ideally, I want the regex engine to stop matching after the closing square bracket of the 'values' array.

Comment: I gather from what you're telling us that 'hover' always is present. Why not just simply `'hover':\['(.*?)',(.*?)]`?

Comment: @ClasG because you should read the question ;) : _Note that there are more charts in the same format before and after the chart whose data I need to get, so I need to identify the right one by its id ('chart-im-looking-for', in this example)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex to grab a specific chart:

```
new lineChart\(['"]([^"']+)["'],\s*(.+?})\s*\)\s*;
```

With the added option: `RegexOptions.Singleline`, this will match until the first occurence of `});`, which is as robust as I can come up with on the spot.

The first capture group of this regex will give you the chart name. The second capture group will provide you with a complete, most likely parsable JSON string. Put it into a JSON parser and access 'values' > 'hover' at will.

## [See it live (ruby, but should work for .net aswell)](http://rubular.com/r/KJdSC4hdw0)

Comment: I guess this is the best approach. This would fail, however, if there is a closing bracket somewhere in the 'new lineChart' declaration. Is it possible to make this regex more foolproof, or the only option is to go with the assumption that there will be no closing brackets?

Comment: Updated the regex to match until first `});` instead of first `)`

Comment: One more question - why use a lookahead (ex. `new lineChart\('chartId',\s*(.+?}(?=\s*\)\s*;))`), instead of a regular match (ex. `new lineChart\('chartId',\s*(.+?})\s*\)\s*;`). Won't results be the same? Are there any benefits to either regex?

Comment: That's a good question, not sure what I was thinking. A lookahead is definitely not needed there.

Comment: Thank you for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the pattern slightly to 1) only match (hover) arrays inside the 'values' array, and 2) to only match those in the correct values array. This is my attempt:

```
(?<=lineChart\('chart-im-looking-for'[^\$]*?'values'\s+:\s+\[([^\[]|\[[^\[]*\])*)\['(.*?)',(.*?)]
                                     ^^^^^<-2    2->^^^^^^/\^^^^^^^^<-1
```

This regex uses some assumptions about the structure of the document, e.g. that there is no $ sign between 'chart-im-looking-for' and its 'values', and that 'values' is followed by `<whitespace>:<whitespace>[`

edit: it should match all hover arrays now.

Comment: This captures only the values in the first 'hover' array. Also, I'd rather avoid making any assumptions about the document, in case there would be a dollar sign in one of the 'lineChart' variables, or the formatting of the document changes along with the number of whitespaces.

Comment: @sdds You have to make some assumptions. You can reduce them by parsing the document in several steps however: first get the whole 'chart-im-looking-for', then extract the values from it, and in a last step get all hover arrays from the values. These are three pretty simple regexes, e.g. the first one is `lineChart\('chart-im-looking-for'(.*?)\);` which makes minimal assumptions about the document. You could even use a JSON parser to parse the whole chart to get all the information of the chart.

Comment: The edited regex still captures only the first 'hover' array values for me. I'm testing it in RegexBuddy on the example data in the question, using the .NET flavour, with and without the 'dot matches newline' option. By the way, using a JSON parser is a great idea, but I still want to get a working regex, just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: @sdds I forgot a `*`. This is my last attempt though :P

Comment: This one seems to be capturing the data from any js arrays further down the source, provided they're not inside of a function beginning with a dollar sign (or whatever that thing is, I'm not familiar with JavaScript/jQuery).